# ELIMINAR CACHÉ FULLCALENDAR

Tags: javascript, laravel, fullcalendar

Estimados la verdad es que no se si este sea el título adecuado para mi pregunta, pero quiero explicar lo mas breve posible mi inquietud, tengo una tabla llamada "dias" donde tengo los siguientes campos.

- $fecha_inicio
- $fecha_fin
- $users_id

Tengo un ***table*** con una lista de usuarios que en cada `<td>` tiene un icono calendario que al dar click me carga los eventos del usuario seleccionado en un fullcalendar en una ventana modal.

hasta aquí todo bien, esto funciona perfecto, mi problema es que al momento de cerrar el modal (sin refrescar la pagina) y seleccionar otro usuario para ver sus eventos me carga los eventos del usuario anterior, pienso que fullcalendar me esta guardando en caché los eventos y no se refrescan al momento de seleccionar otro usuario, sin embargo cuando refresco la pagina me carga los eventos del primer usuario seleccionado.

> ¿Cómo puedo volver a cargar estos eventos según el id del usuario que
>   se seleccionó?

En la documentación de fullcalendar se indica que la recarga de eventos se ejecuta con el siguiente código.

```
$("#event_user").fullCalendar('refetchEvents')
```

Esto no resulto para mi.

**Este es mi script.**

```js
function getDias(id)
{
event.preventDefault();
$("#doctor_id_dia").val(id)
$dias = $('#dias_doctor');
    today = new Date();
    y = today.getFullYear();
    m = today.getMonth();
    d = today.getDate();

    $dias.fullCalendar({
        header: {
            headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
            left: 'title',
            center: 'today prev,next',
            right: 'year,month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listYear, actualizar, agregarEvento',
        },
        defaultDate: today,
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        navLinks: true,
        locale:'es',
        select: function(start, end) {
        start = moment(start.format());
        $("#fecha_inicio_dia").val(start.format("DD-MM-YYYY"));
        $("#modal_form_dias").modal("show")

      },
      editable: true,
      //eventLimit: true, 
      events: {
        url: "/dias-doctor/"+id+"",
        cache: false,
        lazyFetching: false,
      } 
   })
}
```

> Espero haberme explicado bien, quedo atento a sus comentarios,
>   saludos.

Comment: bienvenido!, deberias subir tambien el html o mejor dejar el ejemplo funcionando con la herramienta para compartir codigo que utilizaste, por otro lado el error creo que debe venir porque usas "id" en vez de "class" para referenciar a cada usuario, recuerda que id es para referenciar un único objeto dentro del DOM. yo cambiaria "id=event_user" por "class=event_user" y corregiria el javascript para referenciar a una clase en vez de un id.

Comment: Gracias por responder, voy a integrar el código para ver si podemos ejecutarlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes intentar detectar el cierre de tu ventana modal de la siguiente manera..

```html
$('#modal_form_dias').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
//Detectamos el cierre de nuestra ventana modal bootstrap

  $("#calendar").fullCalendar('removeEvents'); //Con esta linea quitamos
 todos los eventos que están cargados en nuestro calendario

//#Calendar es el DIV en donde estan cargado FullCalendar
})
```

lo pones fuera de tu función de cargar los eventos..

Te dejo 2 enlaces de referencia

[Fullcalendar: How to remove event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34297915/fullcalendar-how-to-remove-event)

[Remover Eventos Fullcalendar (Documentación Oficial)](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/removeEvents)

Comment: Francisco gracias por responder, hice lo que me indicas pero no obtengo lo que necesito.

Comment: Que raro... Otra forma podría ser, que si el calendario que se muestra en el modal no va ser modificado, asignar la variable id=0, y realizar nuevamente la petición de cargar los eventos al cerrar el modal, y obviamente ahora no traerá nada, por consecuente se limpiaría el calendario

Answer (score 1):

Estimado Francisco, te agradezco la ayuda, respecto a lo que mencionaste en la primera respuesta, es la que me funcionó, estaba haciendo referencia a otro modal por eso no obtenía respuesta, eso si, para realizar un refresh a mi calendario utilicé la el siguiente código.

```js
$('#modal_dias').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) { 
        $('#dias_doctor').fullCalendar('destroy'); //este es el div donde se carga el calendario de cada usuario seleccionado.
    })
```

esto lo se puede encontrar aquí también [#2930](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/2930)